# Python typing: is there a way to construct a type for "element of"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm looking for a way to create a type that indicates that a variable is an *element of* some other collection. I know of the Collection type:

```py
from typing import Collection
Foo = Collection[Bar]
```

Instead, I'd like to do the inverse of that, i.e.

```py
Bar = Element[Foo]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

The use-case I have in mind is to be able to something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from gym.spaces import Space, Box, Discrete

Element = ...  # some type definition

def func(x: Element[Box], i: Element[Discrete]) -> Element[Box]:
    """ asserts are implied by the type annotations """
    assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray)
    assert isinstance(i, int)
    return x * i
```

---

Here's a slightly more detailed example using `gym.spaces`:

```py
from gym.spaces import Space, Box, Discrete


box = Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(3,))
dsc = Discrete(5)

x = box.sample()  # example: x = array([0.917, 0.021, 0.740], dtype=float32)
i = dsc.sample()  # example: i = 3


def check(space: Space, y: Element[Space]) -> Element[Space]:
    if y not in space:
        raise ValueError("y not an element of space")
    return y


x = check(box, x)
i = check(dsc, i)
```

Comment: Why don't you just give it the type of the elements directly? Otherwise, you probably just want a `TypeVar`

Comment: I'd like to be able to do `Element[Space]` as well (`Box` and `Discrete` are derived from `Space`).

Comment: I dont know what that means, I am not familiar with that package. Again, you probably just want a type variable, e.g. `Collection[T]` and the. Use `T` when you mean an element. Can you provide a simple example of what you want?

Comment: I added a slightly more detailed example that uses `gym.spaces`. Basically, a `gym.spaces.Space` implements a `space.sample()` and `space.__contains__(elem)` to describe bounded spaces.

Comment: Here's something I stumbled into while learning python. Is this what you are trying to do? [Create custom array[(https://codezup.com/create-own-custom-array-implementation-python/)

Comment: Another one i found is https://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/collections.html

Comment: Thanks @JoeFerndz, but no. I'm specifically interesting in type annotation.

Comment: I will bookmark this. upvoted. Will look forward to how this gets addressed. I will try as well. Good question.

Comment: Fundamentally this depends on how that package is type annotated. Is `Space` type-annotated at all? Ideally, it would be annotated to describe exactly what it contains.  Probably, the best you can do if it isn't is some bound type-variable, bound to some base class that is inherited by all possible classes that it can `__contain__`, or to a discrete selection of those classes. This is nominal typing, not magic. The only way the type system knows about "element of" is by *you telling it*.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Do you mean that I would do something like `SpaceType = TypeVar('Space', bound=gym.spaces.Space)`?

Comment: And if so, how would I define `Element`? If I use `Element = TypeVar('Element')` and then use it as `Element[SpaceType]` I get an error saying that `Element` is not subscriptable. (sorry, I'm pretty new to this typing business)

Comment: No, it has to be bound by the elements spaces can contain, not by space

Comment: There is no direct equivalent to what you want, so don't try to use it that way. If I get back to my keyboard later I'll try to write out an answer but currently I'm on my phone. But you want something like `T = TypeVar('T', Box, Discrete, AnythingElse)` then use `T` as your type

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would my approach compare to sealing what `T` can be by putting everything in `TypeVar`? I sketched out a rough solution, but might have approached it wrong.

Comment: What about using [@typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)? IIUC, you just have two possible options of typing the function, so it's not like you really need a generic solution. Or are you going to use complex spaces as well, like `Dict`, `Tuple`, `MultiDiscrete`?

Comment: I realize, I read your example wrong. But it's still not clear what types are acceptable as elements. Can an `int` go in a `box`? In either case, what I was describing still holds, *you* have to tell the typing system what is acceptable. That can be facilitated if the library is type annotated well, or if you go ahead and write the stubs.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, NewType

T = TypeVar("T")
DiscreteT = NewType("DiscreteT", int)
BoxT = NewType("BoxT", float)

class Space(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def sample(self) -> T: ...
    def __contains__(self, item: T) -> bool: ...

class Discrete(Space[DiscreteT]):
    def __init__(self, n: int) -> None: ...
    def sample(self) -> DiscreteT: ...

class Box(Space[BoxT]):
    def __init__(self, low: float, high: float) -> None: ...
    def sample(self) -> BoxT: ...

def check(space: Space[T], y: T) -> T:
    if y in space:
        raise ValueError("y not an element of space")

    return y

box = Box(low=0, high=1)
dsc = Discrete(5)

x = box.sample()
i = dsc.sample()

# Assumes that these lines are run separately for example's sake, such that assignment from one doesn't impact lines later.
x = check(box, x) # Passes mypy.
i = check(dsc, i) # Passes mypy.

x = check(box, i) # Fails mypy: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "check".
i = check(box, x) # Fails mypy: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "check".

other_dsc = Discrete(0)
i = check(other_dsc, i) # Passes mypy, even though `i` came from `dsc`. Don't know if it is possible for this to be caught at type-check time.
```

I have written the type hints for `Space`, `Discrete` and `Box` as [type stubs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html), such that you can add them if you don't controll the source of `gym.sources`. You should be able to add the `shape` parameter to `Box` pretty easily.

The basic idea here is that we parametrize `Space` with the type of an element it can contain. We use `NewType` in order to make the space elements subtypes of what they fundamentally are (an element sampled from `Discrete` is an `int`, and has `int` properties) without sacrificing the guarantee `check` enforces in that `y` was sampled from `space`.